# SDL_TICKS_PASSED, doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, sdl-2

[SDL_TICKS_PASSED documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TICKS_PASSED)

I am having trouble getting the  "SDL_TICKS_PASSED" function of SDL2 to work, it does not appear to be returning true when I attempt to use it.

```
Uint32 timeout = SDL_GetTicks() + 100;
if( SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), timeout) )
{
    printf( "alarm triggered.............\n" );
}
```

Just reading the documentation, I would guess after 100ms the function would return true and it would display the alarm message.  I may be doing something silly but if anyone has any idea's regarding this issue please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you `SDL_TICKS_PASSED` is called only once. It will return `true` after 100 ticks but it will not block until this timeout happens. So the first call immediately returns `false`. To achieve blocking behavior it should be checked in a loop:

```
Uint32 timeout = SDL_GetTicks() + 100;
while (!SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), timeout))
{
     /* wasting CPU time... */
}
// ok, 100 ticks elapsed when we get here...
```

Or use a dedicated waiting function `SDL_Delay`:

```
SDL_Delay(100);
// ok, 100 ticks elapsed when we get here, no need for loops...
```

Comment: the code example in the documentation linked by the OP has exactly this...

Comment: @rmawatson Yes, but I guess that it is not clearly stated there that behavior of this function is non-blocking. Also all those calls are named somewhat misleading.

Comment: That seems to be the problem or what I'm not understanding, is that it doesn't seem to return true after 100ms.  I don't want to do something similar to SDL_Delay, it stops the entire program from progressing for x amount of time and then it continues.  I guess I was hoping for it to jump back, show the text after 100ms regardless of where it is in the code and then continue on with whatever it was doing, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @jEZTER Control flow can not "jump back". For this function to return `true` it needs to be called *after* timeout elapses.

Comment: If that's the case, that is a bummer.  Anyone know a way to do something like what I was describing without using multi-threading?

Comment: @jEZTER You just need to call it periodically.